# "Cannot create a row ... greater than the allowable maximum row size" error when applying UNION on tables with equal number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

I'm trying to union 5 tables. They each have identical number of columns (300+). I can happily load each table individually.

Error is

> Cannot create a row of size 8161 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.

Which is self explanatory - the entire row combined (of 300+ columns) is too large in memory.

I'm confused how the table was made in the first place and how I could be expected to union? Union does not increase row size, just number of rows, so confused how union could trigger this if they can be SELECTED individually.

Is there a way to repress this limitation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Type conversion can change the size of individual columns.  A `union` query does not require that all columns have exactly the same type, so it allows some implicit conversion.

For instance, this:

```
select convert(tinyint, 1)
union all
select convert(int, 102345678)
```

returns and integer -- three extra bytes compared to the `tinyint`.  This can easily happen for dates and datetimes, and even for national character sets.